# Want to display the text box for particular row in a table in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to display the text box and its update button for which the row I click to edit my value.

[image]

In the above image When I click edit discount to change the discount value for the booking id 6, it shows all the text boxes in all rows like

[image]

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
         <td><?php echo $bookedrow['status'];?></td>
       <td class="discount_val"><?php echo $bookedrow['discount'];?></td>
       <td class="new_discount">
         <input type="text" name="new_discount"/>
          <input class="btn btn-primary" id="update" name="update" value="Update" type="submit"/>
        </td>
       <td><a href="#" class="edit_discount">Edit discount</a></td>
            </tr>
               </tbody>
        </table>
```

JS code:

```
       $('.new_discount').hide();   
 $('.edit_discount').click(function(){
    $('.discount_val').hide(); 
    $('.new_discount').show();

 });
```

Now i want to get the text box and its button for which I'm selecting to update and that value will update for that particular id only.Guide me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use DOM traversal functions to find just the element in the current row:

```
$('.edit_discount').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    row.find(".discount_val").hide();
    row.find(".new_discount").show();
});
```

Comment: That is fixed with your answer @Barmer.now I want to update the new value in table but I cannot update it

Comment: Why can't you update it? After the user edits the value, use a similar code to find the `.discount_val` element in the same row as `.new_discount`, and fill it in with the value.

Comment: i got the result.But now i'm getting another issue @Barmar

Comment: If you have another issue, start another question.

Answer (score 0):

*Smart* Chaining Can do it in one line...

```
 $('.new_discount').hide();   
 $('.edit_discount').click(function(){

     $(this).parent("tr").find(".discount_val").hide().end().find(".new_discount").show();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a better select. `$('.discount_val')` matches all Elements with the class `discount_val`. You could get the parent of the clicked `<a>` and anly sleect the elements with class `discount_val` under this element.

```
var parent = $(this).parent("tr");
$('.discount_val', parent).hide();
$('.new_discount', parent).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('.edit_discount').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.discount_val').hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.new_discount').show(); 
});
```